# In App Update Error. App Won't Restart After Updating. (Unity)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, in-app-update

I tried using the In App Update API from the [PlayCore](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/release-notes) sdk, but after the app auto updates, it didn't restart. When reading the manual, it said if after the app updates and install and it didn't restart, you have to log the error. But when I add the log script for the error handler, it never did log anything.

Here's my code:

```
    private IEnumerator CheckAppUpdate()
    {
        AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = new AppUpdateManager();
        PlayAsyncOperation<AppUpdateInfo, AppUpdateErrorCode> appUpdateInfoOperation = appUpdateManager.GetAppUpdateInfo();

        // Wait until the asynchronous operation completes.
        yield return appUpdateInfoOperation;

        if (appUpdateInfoOperation.IsSuccessful)
        {
            var appUpdateInfoResult = appUpdateInfoOperation.GetResult();
            if (appUpdateInfoResult.UpdateAvailability == UpdateAvailability.UpdateAvailable) {
                updateAvailable = true;
                AppUpdateOptions appUpdateOptions = AppUpdateOptions.ImmediateAppUpdateOptions();
                yield return StartImmediateUpdate(appUpdateManager, appUpdateInfoResult, appUpdateOptions);
            }
        }
        else
            Debug.LogError($"Error:\n{appUpdateInfoOperation.Error}");
    }

    private IEnumerator StartImmediateUpdate(AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager, AppUpdateInfo updateInfo, AppUpdateOptions updateOptions)
    {
        var immediateUpdateRequest = appUpdateManager.StartUpdate(updateInfo, updateOptions);
        yield return immediateUpdateRequest;
        
        //If this Line is reached, the app didn't restart and that means the install failed
        Debug.LogError("Install Update Error:\n" + immediateUpdateRequest.Error);
    }
```

And as you can see from this screenshot of my Error Log, it never reached the Debug.LogError line.
[image: Error Log Screenshot]

PS. I'm using Unity 2020.38.3f and using the Developer Build Option so I can check the log in my editor after I build the apk.

Comment: so find the code that runs before this?

Comment: Try to learn what I asked and what I don't ask bro. This is the only code that runs at the start of the app, that's why it's an immediate update. And besides the code works, only it didn't restart the app and finishes the installation.

Comment: Oh and the one thing that confuses me is why it didn't log any error, because it said that if the app didn't restart then the code after that line will be called. But it didn't even mention the word "Install Update Error". But it did finishes its updates, just not the installation and restart